# CSS Selector for Hover State that is on Same Level

Tags: css

I am wondering how would I write the CSS selector so that when the user hovers over `img.screenshot`, `img.icon` would change its css to `display:block;`.

```
<div class="box">
  <img class="screenshot" src="#">
  <img class="icon"       src="#">
  <p   class="desc">...</p>
</div>

img.icon { display:none; }
```

So far, I have the following statement but am unsure how to select the node when it is on its same level:
`div.box > img.screenshot:hover`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy, sibling selectors:

[Adjacent Sibling Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)

```
img.screenshot:hover + img.icon { /* styles here */ }
```

[General Sibling Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/General_sibling_selectors)

```
img.screenshot:hover ~ img.icon { /* styles here */ }
```